# How do I get back to Fallarbor after jumping over the ledge south of Meteor Falls?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I was going to beat Flannery and I was at Meteor Falls where Team Aqua runs Team Magma out. After I talked to the scientist I left the mountain and went down a one way ledge all the way back to Rustboro city. However I don't think I can get back since Briney (the boat captain) is not at his cabin. Is there any way to get back without the boat?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure I understand the scenario. But if you have rock smash you should be able to go through the cave where you first found Briney now.

Edit: I'm pretty sure you need to have rock smash in the first place to get to meteor falls and back to Rustboro city, so this should be the solution. If you need help finding the cave I'm talking about, let me know.

Comment: I dont think I used rock smash. I do have it but I don't think you fully understand. Let me make it simpler, I'm in rustboro city and I need to get to fallabor. But I can't use the boat, is there another way? Even it's with rock smash. Also the map says route 115 is connected to meteor falls so can I go into it from there?

Comment: No, meteor falls can't be accessed from Rustboro, there's a 1 way ramp which you can jump down from, which is what I think you did. I need to know if you have rock smash, if you do it's very simple. You take the north east exit of Rustboro city, follow the path right until you see a cave entrance. Go in there and follow the path along until you see 2 people either side of crumbled rocks. Break one of the rocks and you will be able to carry on through the cave and exit into a town that will give you access to everywhere you had before (including fallabor).

Comment: Omg I remember those people from my first time going in the cave. I do have rock smash so I'll tell you if it works out.

Comment: You ok now? Make sure not to do it again until you get HM Fly or you'll have to do another lap xD I'm pretty sure I did the same thing back in the day.

Answer (score 1):

After jumping down the ledge south of Meteor Falls, you will end up in Rustboro. This means you will have to backtrack through Rusturf Tunnel and the Route 111 desert to return to Fallarbor. (Of course, this is obviously assuming you do not have HM2 Fly yet. And while I tested it on Emerald, it should also be true for Ruby and Sapphire.)

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck in this same situation. What worked for me was going to my last save point, so it might be a good solution if the damage isn't so detrimental.